# Sunset notification app for Android phones?

Tags: android

I want to lower the family house shutters 1 hour before the actual sunset to save on heating.

I can see 5000 different apps that shows what time will the sun goes down, but didn't found any yet, which warns me when there is the sunset (or 1 hour before).

Is there any?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more why you need it to be an Android app? Other than showing the time, what is the workflow you want the app to trigger? just an alert?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ever considered searching for "sunset alarm"? Immediately brought up [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.caynax.alarmclock) for me. From the description: "sunrise and sunset alarms (with dawn and dusk support)". Going by your description, that should be very close to what you're looking for: dawn would be approx. 20..30min before sunset, right?

Comment: hey @Izzy, Thanks for the app advise, but only the "PRO" version has the alarm for the sunset warning. I tried. But Many Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how can I be more clear than asking "Sunset notification app for Android phones?" :D

Comment: @jim7475 Lockszmith probably wanted to know if you just want to have an allert/a notification presented, or if you'd like to have some actions triggered automatically. For example, my shutters automatically close at sunset (whenever that is), but open at 7am. And the app I mentioned was just the first hit I got on my search, so there might be more. E.g. for photographers, as ~1h before sunset comes pretty close to the "golden hour" ;) And I see you've found one, congrats – and thanks for self-answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sun Alarm" app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vvse.sunalarm&hl=en&gl=US

Finally! Can be set 1 hour before sunset time at my location. no ads, free. wow.